# C++ dll for VBA - problem with reading/encoding strings

Tags: c++, vba, dll

I need to read entries from old-fashioned INI-file with a DLL and after some manipulation export them to VBA code.

The c++ code for the function looks like this:

```
BSTR __stdcall GetSectionEntry(LPCSTR  sSection, LPCSTR  sEntry)
{
    LPCTSTR gszINIfilename = "C:\\test\\test.ini";
    TCHAR localStr[64];
    
    GetFileAttributes(gszINIfilename);
    if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == GetFileAttributes(gszINIfilename) && GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
        bstr_t bstrt = "";
        return bstrt;
    } else {
        GetPrivateProfileStringA(sSection, sEntry, "", localStr, sizeof(localStr), gszINIfilename);
        //_bstr_t bstrt(localStr);
        CComBSTR bstrt(localStr);
        return bstrt;
    }
}
```

The VBA (Word 2016):

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSectionEntry Lib "test.dll" (ByVal sSection As String, ByVal sEntry As String) As String

For i = 0 To 5
    Debug.Print ("Name = " & StrConv(GetSectionEntry("Name", CStr(i)), vbFromUnicode))
Next i
```

End finally the INI-file:

```
[Name]
0=123456789012345678901234567
1=1234567890123456789012345678
2=1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901
3=12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
```

I compiled the DLL using VS2019 with either "Character Set" set to "Not Set" or to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".

Debugging in VS shows that the strings are *properly* formatted (for example for 1 it's L"1234567890123456789012345678"). I tested it with different sizes of localStr (64..1024). I tried  *bstr_t* and *CComBSTR* and a few more. In all cases *print.debug* in VBA shows following result:

```
Name = 123456789012345678901234567
Name = ??????????????  ????????????
Name = ??????????????????????????????1 ?? ??????????????yu ?  rg|A ?
Name = 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
```

Any string that is longer than 27 and shorter than 62 characters is not properly encoded. When I checked them without *StrConv(string, vbFromUnicode)* they were missing all even null-characters.
For that reason they are then encoded as some Asian characters:

[image]

The same happens for string that are 13--14 character long:

[image]

I'm very sure that I'm doing something trivial and stupid but I never had to write any C/C++ for windows. I would be grateful if anyone could point my mistake and correct me.

Comment: Do you really have to read via this DLL instead of straight from the INI  ?

Comment: @yves-daoust : yes, I do. I wouldn't ask. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CComBSTR bstrt(localStr);
    return bstrt;
```

This return statement converts the CComBSTR to a BSTR, and returns that, and then destroys the CComBSTR since it's no longer in scope. When the CComBSTR object is destroyed [the string is freed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class?view=msvc-160#dtor).

Try `return bstrt.Detach();` which [detaches the string from the CComBSTR object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class?view=msvc-160#detach) so it won't be freed by the destructor.

After you return it, the string "belongs" to VBA and it's VBA's job to free it, which I *assume* it does automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast...
I've recompiled and it seems everything looks fine.